# Excel VBA nested for-loop outputs replicated/wrong results

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I have a nested for loop that iterates through the birthday years ( year 1919 to 2001) for two different people.

The purpose is to find every age combination (based on the birth dates) for the two people.

The issue I have is that the age of the person in the nested loop (the loop with variable j) seems to repeat sometimes and randomly with no pattern.

For example, every combination when person N is ages 100-20 works fine with no repeated age value for person J. Then all the sudden, when person N is aged 19 person J would go from age 100-50 then would be aged 49 twice and then go to age 47.

The following is my code:

```
Sub ChangeDOB()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim n As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
i = 2

For n = 1919 To 2001
    Sheets("Inputs").Range("E6").FormulaR1C1 = "1/15/" & n
    'j = 1919

    For j = 1919 To 2001
        Sheets("FF Tool Rates").Range("B" & i).Value = Sheets("Inputs").Range("E7").Value
        Sheets("Inputs").Range("E10").FormulaR1C1 = "1/15/" & j

        Sheets("FF Tool Rates").Range("C" & i).Value = Sheets("Inputs").Range("E11").Value
        Sheets("FF Tool Rates").Range("D" & i).Value = Sheets("Inputs").Range("S8").Value
        i = i + 1
    Next j
Next n
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The formula in Inputs!E7 calculates Person N's Age. Formula in Inputs!E11 calculates person J's Age. Formula in Inputs!S8 calculates a value based on the two person's age. I hope this adds clarity.

The following is an example of the expected result:

```
Person N Age   Person J Age
90             90
90             89
90             88
90             87
90             86
90             85
90             84
90             83
90             82
90             81
```

The following is an example of an error result (see how age 85 appears twice):

```
Person N Age   Person J Age
33             90
33             89
33             88
33             87
33             85 <-should've been 86
33             85 
33             84
33             83
33             82
33             81
```

Initially I thought it was the way I set up Excel that calculates the age based on birth dates. But if I manually inputted the year in the cells, Excel produces non-repeated results. So age 85 does not appear twice with manual input.

There seems to be no pattern regarding when this error appears and if I re-run the code sometimes there will be no error and sometimes the error appears somewhere else. That is why it's been difficult for me to debug this.

Any suggestions or advice on where I might have missed something or if I messed up any logic in my code?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: a) Your `"1/15/" & n` style date constructions should be `DateSerial(n, 1, 15)` and `DateSerial(j, 1, 15)` in cells formatted as dates. b) It seems you have formulas in Inputs!E7, Inputs!E11 and Inputs!S8. You should have included those since your results are dependent on them.

Comment: (1/2) Hi! Thank you for your comment and I apologize for not getting back to you earlier on this. a.) I updated the formula to use the DateSerial function. After applying this change there are still errors in the output. b.) The portion of the spreadsheet that I'm using VBA on is small part of a much bigger file. Therefore, the formulas in Inputs!E7,11 and S8 are linking other parts of the spreadsheet so the formulas themselves are not useful unless you're looking at the spreadsheet as a whole.

Comment: (2/2) I manually tested the errors by playing around with the year inputs that's giving me the wrong error. Inputs!E7, Inputs!E11 and Inputs!S8 all produced the right results during the manual test so I don't think the formula in those cells is what's producing the error. Just by looking at the logic of the code, can you spot any logic errors? Is it possible that Excel's VBA run "too fast" for the formulas to process the change and that's what's resulting in the wrong value?

Comment: To clarify: formula in Inputs!E7 calculates Person N's Age. Formula in Inputs!E11 calculates person J's Age. Formula in Inputs!S8 calculates a value based on the two person's age. I hope this adds clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the exact same problem, your question was the only one I found that seemed like its answer could help me. Too bad there weren't any answers.

I ended up fixing it, so hopefully this will help others:

I have a Workbook that calculates product prices based on 4 variables (that are themselves divided among different sheets and other workbooks). Variable `a` has 25 possibilities, `b` has 52, `c` has 3, and `d` has 6. That gives me 22,464 different price possibilities. My code has 4 nested loops to print each possibility in a different row, so I can import the output to a different system.
The problem I was running into was that, besides taking almost 30 minutes to run on a high end computer, I would randomly get rows with the wrong data.

My (unconfirmed) diagnosis was that, because within the `For` loops there was a lot of calculation going on elsewhere in the sheet (actually, anywhere within Excel), sometimes VBA would continue iterating and would fill out the next row before the source had had a chance to update.
That is why when I'd step debug the error wouldn't show up, and why it was intermittent and seemingly random even when running the code as a whole.

I started by using `With` to streamline my code and avoid VBA going through the whole `Workbooks` and `Worksheets` arrays with each line of code. I also created `Excel.Workbook`, `Excel.Worksheet`, and `Excel.Range` variables for each of my many references.

What ultimately seems to have fixed it, though, was adding `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` to the beginning of the sub, and `Application.Calculate` to the appropriate point in the nested loops. I added a check for `Application.CalculationState` and then a `DoEvents`, but I'm not even sure how to test if that works.

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
Sub test()
    '
    ' (Variable declarations suppressed)
    '
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
    'Set to manual
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        
    For a = 0 To 22464
        rngTabCusto.Value = wksCalculos.Cells(a / 936 + 23, 28).Value
        For b = 0 To 918
            rngFrete.Value = wksFrete.Cells(b / 18 + 4, 1).Value
            For c = 0 To 12
                rngTipoFat.Value = wksCalculos.Cells(c / 6 + 3, 3).Value

                '
                ' Calculate sheets after changing variables
                '
                Application.Calculate
                
                '
                ' Waits until calculations are done
                '
                If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
                    DoEvents
                End If
                
                '
                ' Prints calculation results
                '
                With wksDescontos
                    For d = 0 To 5
                        .Cells(a + b + c + d + 2, 1).Value = rngEstab.Value
                        .Cells(a + b + c + d + 2, 2).Value = wksOrcamento.Cells(2, d + 2).Value
                        .Cells(a + b + c + d + 2, 3).Value = rngContrib.Value
                        .Cells(a + b + c + d + 2, 4).Value = wksRegiao.Cells(b / 18 + 2, 1).Value
                        .Cells(a + b + c + d + 2, 5).Value = wksRegiao.Cells(b / 18 + 2, 2).Value
                        .Cells(a + b + c + d + 2, 6).Value = wksOrcamento.Cells(4, d + 2).Value
                        .Cells(a + b + c + d + 2, 7).Value = rngTabOrc.Value
                        .Cells(a + b + c + d + 2, 8).Value = data
                        .Cells(a + b + c + d + 2, 11).Value = rngFat.Value
                    Next d
                End With
            c = c + 5
            Next c
        b = b + 17
        Next b
    a = a + 935
    Next a
    
    'Reset
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```